# No such directory after creating it

Tags: command-line, directory, cd-command

I'm taking a basic Unix course and right now we're learning terminal. 
My directions are 
create a directory called company and subdirectories called sales, accounting and marketing. 
So I did that.

```
mkdir company
cd company
mkdir sales
mkdir accounting
mkdir marketing
```

And then create files called `file1`, `file2` and `file3` inside `company`.

```
touch file1
touch file2
touch file3
```

And then copy file 1 2 and 3 to the 3 subdirectories I have created but I'm stuck on copying it to the first directory.

```
cp company/file1 company/file2 company/file3 company/sales
```

But the terminal prints an error, "cp: target 'company/sales' is not a directory."
How is this the case when I just made a directory called sales,  and when I ls inside of company it lists the sales folder?

```
cd company
ls
accounting file1 file2 file3 marketing sales
```

Comment: What is your `pwd` when you run that `cp` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in the `company` directory then try this:

```
cp file1 sales
cp file2 sales
```

OR

```
cp file1 sales; cp file2 sales
```

Or

```
cp file1 file2 file3 sales
```

The last is the easiest and can accomplish copying all files it a single subdirectory in one line. If you want to complete the task and copy each file to each subdirectory in one line, merge the second and third example like this:

```
cp file1 file2 file3 sales; cp file1 file2 file3 accounting; cp file1 file2 file3 marketing
```

One last example is this:

```
for d in */; do cp file* "$d"; done
```

The `file*` is locating every thing within the current directory that starts with "file" and copies it to every first-level subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you!
I didn't know it mattered that I was already in the company directory but that fixed it. And thanks for the easy way to do it.

Comment: @joe32 Anytime and glad to help. If this answered your question, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer.